# How to combine a Bidirectional LSTM layer with a Covnet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

For example I have the following model below,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True),input_shape=(X.shape[1],X.shape[2]),merge_mode='concat'))

keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D()

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy" , optimizer="adam" , metrics=["accuracy"])
```

However, I am not sure how to make the Conv1D work with the LSTM layer. Is this even possible at all? The input data is in the format of,

```
X = X.reshape(-1,10,64)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1D convolutions and LSTMs use the same input shape: `(batchSize, lengthOrSteps, featuresOrChannels)`.

So, it's totally ok to stack them together.

You will need the LSTM to have `return_sequences=True` for that, so it keeps the `lengthOrSteps` dimension. Otherwise it will return just `(batchSize,cells)` instead of `(batchSize,lengthOrSteps,cells)`.

But even though, there is no obligation to connect them like this. 
In fact you can connect everything to everything, as long as you shape things properly. (Using `Reshape()` layers, for instance). The possibilities are unlimited.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add that I already tried setting the return_sequences to true and still got an error. Below is my error,

    keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D()
  File "/home/kiranjyot.gill/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Not sure why its saying this at all

Comment: You're not creating your layer properly. you need to give it the number of filters, and the kernel size. `model.add(Conv1D(filters=25,kernel_size=3))`, for instance.

Comment: This may also be a problem in the LSTM layer, you created it with `LSTM(100,)` - There is a comma without anything after it.

Comment: I appreciate the speedy reply. Your idea seems to have worked but after defining the filters=25 and the kernel_size=3 I got a new error.  model.fit(X, Y,validation_split=.10, epochs=36, batch_size=10,class_weight='auto')
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5013, 1)

Comment: I corrected the comma mistake. In my code it was fine but I forgot to fix it on Stackoverflow

Comment: That happens because the Dense layer is receiving an input with shape `(batchSize,length,filters)`, and it's keeping the length dimension at the end, but your result doesn't have a lenght. You can add a `Flatten()` layer before the `Dense` layer.